# How to reduce whitespace width when using bullet list inside table

Tags: tables, itemize, overleaf

I want to reduce the whitespace width between table column line and bullet inside a table. I am using following code to generate the table.

```
\begin{table}[htb]
\centering
\caption{Table test}
\label{tab:test}
\begin{tabular}{|p{0.05\linewidth}|p{0.3\linewidth}|p{0.25\linewidth}|p{0.3\linewidth}|}
\hline
\textbf{T} & \textbf{Title 1} & \textbf{Title 2} & \textbf{Title 3} \\
\hline
T1 & Text 1 & Text 2 &
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.3\textwidth}
    \begin{itemize}
    \item Item 1
   \end{itemize}
  \end{minipage} \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

The output is as follows

[image]

I want to reduce the width highlighted in red line in the shown image. Does anyone know how to do this? Thank you

Comment: Please provide MWE! In preamble it should have to your problem relevant packages and commands definitions. This seems to be easy to reach by `enumitem` package and list option `leftmargin=*`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Edit:**
Table is now inserted in `table` float environment, added are caption and label for referencing table. As request OP in his comment below:

By guessing what you have (or haven't) in your document preamble use one of my table test container for construct a MWE ...

With `enumitem` package and defining of new list ter use `tabularray` for table, a MWE with your table can be:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[skip=1ex, 
            font=small, labelfont=bf]{caption}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\newlist{tabitemize}{itemize}{1}% <-- defined new list
\setlist[tabitemize]{nosep,     % <-- new list setup
                     leftmargin = *          ,
                     label      = \textbullet,
                     after=\end{minipage},                  % <---
                     before=\begin{minipage}[t]{\linewidth} % <---
                     }
\usepackage{tabularx}
\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\hsize=#1\hsize\linewidth=\hsize%
                       \raggedright\arraybackslash}X}
                       
\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[ht]
\caption{My table}
\label{tab:mytble}
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{|l|L{1.1}|L{0.8}|L{1.1}|}
    \hline
\textbf{T} & \textbf{Title 1} & \textbf{Title 2} & \textbf{Title 3} \\
    \hline
T1  & Text 1    & Text 2    &   \begin{tabitemize}
                            \item Item 1
                            \item Item 2
                                \end{tabitemize}   \\
    \hline
\end{tabularx}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: +1. On the off-chance that the "looks" of the document's text and math font families happen to be quite different, I'd replace `label=$\bullet$` with `label=\textbullet`, though.

Comment: @Mico, you are right. I must correct my old "container" for table code testing  from where come this discrepancy. Corrected now.

Comment: @Zarko Thank you for your answer. I removed "after=\end{minipage},               before=\begin{minipage}[t]{\linewidth}" because they didn't compile. Also, with tabularx usage, I couldn't put \caption, \label commands to refer the table.

Comment: @YatShan, my MWE perfectly compile, result is showed in answer. By removing this option your list become awful ...

Comment: @Zarko When I added "\setlist[tabitemize]{nosep, leftmargin = *, label = \textbullet, after=\end{minipage}, before=\begin{minipage}[t]{\linewidth}}", it says "unclosed open group { found at \end{minipage} unexpected \end{minipage} unclosed \end{minipage}"

Comment: @Zarko Also, do you know how to add caption and label to this table ? As I have refer this table in the text.

Comment: @YatShan, answer follow what you say in question :-). See edited answer, will appear asap.

Comment: @YatShan, does answer solve your problem? If yes, than you may consider to accept it (by clicking on check mark at top left side of answer. BTW, as >I see you so far not accept asny received answer. Why, Or no one fulfil your expectation?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/136663/discussion-between-yatshan-and-zarko).

Comment: @Zarko, it worked well, thanks for your answer.